# jq having issues escaping hypens in top level key

Tags: json, key, jq

This is my json that i am trying to just jq to parse:

```
{
    "aaa-bbb-ccc": {
        "derp": blah
    }
}
```

Getting error this error:

```
cat myjson | jq -r .'aaa-bbb-ccc' 

jq: error: aaa/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.aaa-bbb-ccc    
jq: error: bbb/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.aaa-bbb-ccc           
jq: error: ccc/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the basic form for accessing a key's value, you'd write:

```
jq -r '.["KEYNAME"]'
```

except that at a Windows prompt, you'd have to fiddle with the quotation marks (or put the filter in a file).

In modern versions of jq, the basic form can be abbreviated to just `."KEYNAME"`.

So, assuming your jq is 1.5 or later, you could write (avoiding `cat`):

```
jq -r '."aaa-bbb-ccc"' myjson
```

For further details, see the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ).